# Function that creates unique reference no

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have an asp.net application that uses SQL Server 2005. In this application I want to create a function that returns unique reference numbers for new Inquiry Id.

I read about `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` but it has a specific format like `1548C3E02-2D73-4244-8787-D45AC590519A`.

I want output like `1703-HJIF-2012`. Here first have combination of current datepart like date and month, second is random string which auto generate and third one is year part of current date. I don't have any idea how I could create such a function and how I would be calling this function from a stored procedure and get result string from function with this required format.

Please help me..

Comment: Why do you want this format as an identifier?

Comment: for example in Customer Replationship management if we create Ticket. this ticket is created with specific reference no. for this idea i want to auto generate reference no with sql function or any other RowGUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do that is to use the `rand()` built-in function to generate the random string (the middle part of your reference number). Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't allow you to create a non-deterministic function which basically means you can't call `rand()`  from within your own function.

An easy (but slightly ugly) workaround is to pass the random string in as a parameter because you are allowed to call `rand()` from a stored procedure. Sounds confusing? This is what it should look like (assuming your random string should only contain uppercase letters):

```
create function UniqueRefNum (@r1 float, @r2 float, @r3 float, @r4 float)
returns char(14)
begin
    -- Not sure if rand() might return 1.0
    -- If it does, the conversion code below would produce a character that's not an
    -- uppercase letter so let's avoid it just in case
    if @r1 = 1.0 set @r1 = 0
    if @r2 = 1.0 set @r2 = 0
    if @r3 = 1.0 set @r3 = 0
    if @r4 = 1.0 set @r4 = 0

    declare @now datetime
    set @now = getdate() -- or getutcdate()

    declare @m char(2)
    if month(@now) < 10
        set @m = '0' + month(@now)
    else
        set @m = month(@now)

    declare @d char(2)
    if day(@now) < 10
        set @d = '0' + day(@now)
    else
        set @d = day(@now)

    return @m + @d + '-' + 
           char(65 + cast(@r1 * 26 as int)) + 
           char(65 + cast(@r2 * 26 as int)) + 
           char(65 + cast(@r3 * 26 as int)) + 
           char(65 + cast(@r4 * 26 as int)) + 
           '-' + cast(year(@now) as varchar)
end
```

You then call the function from your stored procedure like this:

```
declare @uniqueRef char(14)
set @uniqueRef = dbo.UniqueRefNum(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand())
```

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. Try calling it a few times with ``select dbo.UniqueRefNum(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand())`` and see the results.

Comment: Ur function create space instead of 0.